# how to display data on only Existing rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am looking to show data of only existing row

My expected output should be

```
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+
| vendor_name   | purchases | available_quantity |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+
| X1            |       190 |                 25 |
| X2            |       118 |                  5 |
| X3            |         4 |                  0 |
| X4            |        41 |                  0 |
| X5            |        13 |                  0 |
| X6            |       121 |                  0 |
```

my actual output is

```
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+
| vendor_name   | purchases | available_quantity |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+
| X1            |       190 |                 25 |
| X2            |       118 |                 5 |
| X3            |         4 |                 25 |
| X4            |        41 |                 5 |
| X5            |        13 |                 25 |
| X6            |       121 |                 5 |
```

As you see the actual output is geting X1's & X2'S quantity shows in all rows where x1 & X2 data only existing in B table.

Please help me to get the solution to get the expected output as you see above
Used mysql queries

Example - if X3 is not present in B table should be 0

````
select pq.vendor_name,
    purchases,spurchases as available_quantity 
    from (select vendor_name,sum(quantity) as A from purchases group by vendor_name) pq,(select vendor_name,sum(quantity) as spurchases from B group by vendor_name) sq```
````